# Chrome DevTools show an empty outgoing binary web socket frame when it is not really empty

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

Chrome DevTools recently gained an ability to preview binary web socket frames:

[WebSocket binary message viewer](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/devtools#binary)

I decided to test it out so I built a simple web socket echo tester and a ping web socket client and to my surprise, my incoming binary frames work perfectly and are previewed by the developer tools, but outgoing ones report incorrect length of zero bytes and show no data. I know the frame is correct because the server just echoes it back so it if was broken, it would echo an incorrect frame back.

My test client code looks like this:

```
const blob = new Blob(['BINARY']);
webSocket.send(blob);
```

And the server just pings it back:

```
await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
```

You can see the full server and client implementation [in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/TomasHubelbauer/net-core-web-socket-server).

Outgoing frame:

[image: outgoing frame]

Incoming frame:

[image: icoming frame]

What could be causing Chrome to display the outgoing frame incorrectly? Am I constructing the blob wrong perhaps?

Comment: I think this might be a Chrome issue so I filled a bug with them: https://crbug.com/962857.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a Chrome error, my Chromium bug https://crbug.com/962857 tracks the progress on it.

A workaround is to send binary frames by providing `ArrayBuffer` or typed array payloads, not `Blob`s.

An example which encodes a string to a typed array (`Uint8Array`) and sends it follows:

```
const uint8Array = new TextEncoder().encode('BINARY');
webSocket.send(uint8Array);
```

[image]